# Parse Date to timestamp

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, date

I have such response from server `Date = "/Date(1348783200000+0200)/"` how can I parse it to timestamp or date (example: Monday 21, September, 2012)?? please help..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your date is in milliseconds. You will need to divide by 1000 and cast it into an `NSDate` after that. Then you can just use `NSDateFormatter` with `NSDateFormatterLongStyle` to show the date in that format.

```
NSTimeInterval dateInterval = dateWithMilliseconds;
dateInterval = dateInterval / 1000;
NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:dateInterval];

NSDateFormatter *formatter = [NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterLongStyle];
NSString *dateString = [formatter stringFromDate:date];
```